# Поворот объекта в OpenGL 1.0 относительно заданной точки

Tags: opengl

Как повернуть объект относительно заданной точки в OpenGL 1.0?
Объект рисуется **с центром в точке 0,0,0**(начале мировых координат). Я могу его вращать с помощью **glRotate()** относительно центра объекта, но в некоторых случаях необходимо вращение относительно другой точки.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Перемести центр объекта в заданную точку. Тогда вращение будет вокруг нее.

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin Я понял это. Опишите подробнее

Comment: ты как делаешь ? на 1ой версии openGL ? или ES 2.0 через шейдеры ?

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin OpenGL 1.0(GL10)

Comment: я с первой никогда не работал. Но попробуй может вертексы изменить так чтобы центром объекта у тебя была та точка вокруг которой ты хочешь вращать. Ну например у тебя квадрат в координатах {-1,-1} {1,1} центр у него 0,0, а если ты задашь квадрат {0,0}{1,1} у него уже центр вращения будет в углу, а не в центре фигуры. + transtale куда надо и вращай как хочешь.

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin спасибо, так и сделал. Я еще новичек, если удалю вопрос, ничего критичного не произойдет?)

Comment: зачем оставь вдруг у кого-то будет такой же вопрос. P.S. и забей на openGL 1.0 это прошлый век, не трать зря время, выдели неделю разберись с шейдерами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x`, `y`, `z` - точка относительно которой нужно повернуть

`a` - угол поворота

```
glTranslate(-x, -y, -z);
glRotate(a, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslate(x, y, z);
glDraw...
```